# PySpark - Collect vs CrossJoin, which to choose to create a max column?

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, collect

Spark Masters!

Does anyone has some tips on which is better or faster on pyspark to create a column with the max number of another column.

Option A:

```
max_num = df.agg({"number": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
df = df.withColumn("max", f.lit(max_num))
```

Option B:

```
max_num = df2.select(f.max(f.col("number")).alias("max"))
df2 = df2.crossJoin(max_num)
```

Please feel free, to add any other comments, even not directly related, is more for learning purpose.

Please, feel free to add an option C, D …

On thread is a testable code I made (also any comments on the code are welcome)

Testing code:

```
import time
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as f

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 01 - Data creation
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = []
for i in range(10000):
    data.append(
        {
            "1": "adsadasd",
            "number": 1323,
            "3": "andfja"
         }
    )
    data.append(
        {
            "1": "afasdf",
            "number": 8908,
            "3": "fdssfv"
         }
    )
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df.count()
df2.count()
print(df.rdd.getNumPartitions())
print(df2.rdd.getNumPartitions())
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 02 - Tests

# B) Crossjoin
start_time = time.time()
max_num = df2.select(f.max(f.col("number")).alias("max"))
df2 = df2.crossJoin(max_num)
print(df2.count())
print("Collect time: ", time.time() - start_time)

# A) Collect
start_time = time.time()
max_num = df.agg({"number": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
df = df.withColumn("max", f.lit(max_num))
print(df.count())
print("Collect time: ", time.time() - start_time)


df2.show()
df.show()
```

Measure the performance of collect and crossjoin on pyspark.

Answer (score 1):

I added another method similar to your B method, which consists in creating a `Window` over all dataframe and then taking the maximum value on it:

```
df3.withColumn("max", F.max("number").over(Window.partitionBy()))
```

---

Here is how the three methods performed over a dataframe of 100 million rows (I couldn't fit much more into memory):

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 01 - Data creation
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = pd.DataFrame({
  'aaa': '1',
  'number': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=100000000)
})
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(data)

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 02 - Tests

# A) Collect
method = 'A'
start_time = time.time()
max_num = df.agg({"number": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
df = df.withColumn("max", F.lit(max_num))
print(f"Collect time method {method}: ", time.time() - start_time)

# B) Crossjoin
method = 'B'
start_time = time.time()
max_num = df2.select(F.max(F.col("number")).alias("max"))
df2 = df2.crossJoin(max_num)
print(f"Collect time method {method}: ", time.time() - start_time)

# C) Window
method = 'C'
start_time = time.time()
df3 = df3.withColumn("max", F.max("number").over(Window.partitionBy()))
print(f"Collect time method {method}: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

Results:

```
Collect time method A:  1.890228033065796
Collect time method B:  0.01714015007019043
Collect time method C:  0.03456592559814453
```

I tried the same code also with 100k rows; method A halves its collect time (~0.9 sec) but it's still high, whereas method B and C stay more or less the same.

No other sensible methods came to mind.
Therefore, it seems that method B may be the most efficient one.

Comment: Thanks for the awesome new option and the code. 


Just want to point out that we actually need an 'Action' (count(), show(), collect() ...) on the experiments so that we can count the transformation time.

Is good to put an action right after the df creation too, to avoid increasing the time of loading the data. 

I actually got this times, with this changes

Comment: You're right, I erroneously deleted those code lines

Answer (score 0):

Made some changes to @ric-s great suggestion.

```
import time
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 01 - Data creation
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

data = pd.DataFrame({
  'aaa': '1',
  'number': np.random.randint(0, 100, size=1000000)
})
df = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(data)
df3 = spark.createDataFrame(data)

df.count()
df2.count()
df3.count()
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# 02 - Tests

# A) Collect
method = 'A'
start_time = time.time()
max_num = df.agg({"number": "max"}).collect()[0][0]
df = df.withColumn("max", F.lit(max_num))
df.count()
print(f"Collect time method {method}: ", time.time() - start_time)

# B) Crossjoin
method = 'B'
start_time = time.time()
max_num = df2.select(F.max(F.col("number")).alias("max"))
df2 = df2.crossJoin(max_num)
df2.count()
print(f"Collect time method {method}: ", time.time() - start_time)

# C) Window
method = 'C'
start_time = time.time()
df3 = df3.withColumn("max", F.max("number").over(Window.partitionBy()))
df3.count()
print(f"Collect time method {method}: ", time.time() - start_time)
```

And got this results:

```
Collect time method A:  1.8250329494476318
Collect time method B:  1.373009204864502
Collect time method C:  0.4454350471496582
```